# Which form is better used for email subject?

Tags: grammar

How should I write email subject:

> Your application is received

or

> Your application has been received

I understand the difference between tenses, but not sure which one is more suitable for this specific case.

Answer (score 1):

"Your application has been received" is preferable to "Your application is received."

Why? Because the latter sounds incomplete. It would sound better if it were followed by "and we are reviewing it," but that additional thought can appear and be developed within the email.

Question: Why not word the subject with "We have received your application"?